# Launch pg_restore via CMD with PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, python, postgresql, cmd

I try to restore a database (".backup" file) with pg_restore with cmd launch with PHP code but it doesn't work.

**1-** I give to my PHP variable all the cmd code

```
$cmd="cmd /c C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_restore.exe -d ".$_POST['data2']." -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U ********** D:/backup/voirie.backup";
```

**2-** I launch it

```
exec($cmd);
```

My php work without result

[image]

On my server the process is launched

[image]

*Other informations*

- In place of exec() I tested with system() and passthru()
- I tested to create a batchfile from my php. This batchfile, work fine when  launch him on the server but not from my PHP file
- The generate code in $cmd was tested directly from CMD on the server and it works
- For other codes on this server I use this who work fine: `system("cmd /c C:/Python35-32/python.exe D:/python/serpent.py");`
- I tested with this quotes without result : `$cmd='cmd /c "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_restore.exe" -d '.$_POST['data2'].' -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U ********** D:/backup/voirie.backup';`

Comment: The problem is probably the space in `Program Files`.  Escape that and try again.

Comment: I tried this `$cmd="cmd /c C:/program files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_restore.exe -d ".$_POST['data2']." -i -h ...`, this $cmd="cmd /c C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_restore.exe -d ".$_POST['data2']." -i -h ...`, this `$cmd="cmd /c C:/program files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_restore.exe -d ".$_POST['data2']." -i -h ...` and this `$cmd="cmd /c \"\"C:\\program files\\PostgreSQL\\9.1/bin\\pg_restore.exe -d \"\".$_POST['data2']." -i -h ...` without gorgeous progress

Comment: That's work with this on server with cmd shell `pg_restore -d provisoire -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U ********** D:/backup/voirie.backup` but not with my PHP but after few seconds the process stop

Comment: I'd use [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what process is really started, what it does and why it fails.